# Como passar o valor de uma variável no JSP para outra no Javascript?

Tags: jsp

Estou tentando definir o valor de uma variável dentro de uma tag `script` com linguagem de expressão do JSP. Tentei assim para verificar se o valor não era vazio:

```xml
<c:if test="${!empty newsletter.id}">
<script>
   $(function(){
      alert("Entrou no 'if'");
   })
</script>
</c:if>
```

E funcionou, o *alert* foi exibido normalmente (então o atributo `newsletter.id` não está vazio). Tentei então definir o valor da variável assim:

```xml
<c:if test="${!empty newsletter.id}">
<script>
   $(function(){
      var foo = ${newsletter.content}; /* aqui... */
      alert(foo);
   });
</script>
</c:if>
```

E pronto, o *alert* parou de ser exibido. Até cheguei a pensar que era algo por causa da sintaxe `${...}` com a do jQuery `$(...)` e tentei assim:

```xml
<c:if test="${!empty newsletter.id}">
<script>
   var foo = ${newsletter.content}; /* tentei fora do document.ready(...) */
   $(function(){
      alert(foo);
   });
</script>
</c:if>
```

Também não foi exibido o *alert*.

O problema está sendo na hora de atribuir o valor de `newsletter.content` para a variável `foo` no Javascript. Como eu faço para atribuir um valor de uma variável JSP à uma variável dentro da tag `script`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var foo = '${newsletter.content}';
```

Ao colocar os apóstrofos, tudo o que estiver em `newsetter.content` será colocado dentro de uma String. Na verdade você está usando Java para gerar código Javascript, então se o conteúdo de `newsletter.content` fosse "olá mundo" por exemplo, da forma que estava iria gerar o seguinte código js:

```js
var foo = olá mundo;
```

Agora com os apóstrofos o código gerado é:

```js
var foo = 'olá mundo';
```