# console.log não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, jsp

O que estou fazendo de errado?
Porque o console.log não está funcionando quando eu insiro a variavel via JSP?
Aparece o seguinte erro:

> index.jsp:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>
> ```
> at eval (<anonymous>)
>
> at jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
> ```

Segue abaixo o código:

```
<select id="cargo" name="cargo">
    <option value=""></option>                                                            
    <% 
       List<String> cargos = FuncApp.obterCargos();
       String sListaCargo;
       for(int i = 0; i < cargos.size(); i++) {
           sListaCargo = cargos.get(i);
    %>
    <script>
        console.log("sListaCargo:" + <%= sListaCargo %> );
    </script>
    <option value='<%= sListaCargo %>' <%= (sCargo.equals(sListaCargo)) ? "selected='selected'" : "" %>> <%= sListaCargo %> </option>                                                                
    <% 
       } //fecha for
    %>        
</select>
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Como passar o valor de uma variável no JSP para outra no Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62965/4808)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente `<%= sListaCargo %>` esta retornando uma string, só teria efeito da maneira que fez se ele fosse para o JavaScript um formato que fosse interpretado como `Number`, `Object`, `Array`, `Boolean`, no caso se for uma string ele será renderizado como:

```
 console.log("sListaCargo:" + foo bar );
```

O `foo bar` seria um exemplo de texto, logo o que tem que fazer é:

```
 console.log("sListaCargo: <%= sListaCargo %>");
```

Isso porque JSP roda no back-end e **não se comunica diretamente** com o front-end, o JSP é baixado para o navegador como se fosse uma página HTML real.

Um detalhe, se tratando do `console.log`, você pode mudar para isto:

```
 console.log("sListaCargo", "<%= sListaCargo %>");
```

Pois o `console.log` aceita múltiplos parâmetros, mas é só sugestão, não afeta a funcionalidade principal.